# iPhone 6 and iPhone X: Mail app not showing attachments correctly

Tags: iphone, mail.app, email

I have been encountering issues with both an iPhone 6 and an iPhone X using Apple Mail app. When receiving multiple automated reports from SRSS, the attachments will **clone** from other, similar reports.

On other phones, this behavior does not seem to happen, as it does not seem to happen on PCs. This lead me to believe it being an issue with iOS/Mail app. The reports are sent in HTML Web archive format through e-mail.

I have researched on the Internet regarding this issue, and mostly I found people reporting this issue, but I haven't found many solutions.

I would like to know what could be done about this. If possible, I would rather not install a secondary application for work e-mails on these phones but if this is the only option then I'd do it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) As the first resolution step, you can try by using the official mail app of the email service provider, such as Yahoo mail, Gmail, Outlook etc. That way you'll be rule it out as a bug in Apple's Mail app.

Comment: Using the Outlook app seemingly fixed the issue on one of the two devices, i do not have ready access to the second. It appears to be an issue with the stock app as i immagined, i wonder if there is any way to make it work properly instead of resorting to downloading a secondary email app

Comment: If the Internet searches are reporting issue being faced commonly and not having any solution, the most likely explanation is that it's a bug in the Mail app. The official app from the email service provider is more likely to work bug-free compared to OS stock app. If Outlook is working fine on one device it will very likely work fine on the other device too. It would be advised to use Outlook app instead of Mail.

Comment: Yes, of course. The only issue is that the end user seems reluctant to install additional applications when there already is one serving the purpose that cannot be deleted and thus wants the integrated one to be working. Thanks for the help regardless and for having confirmed my idea on the issue.

Comment: Mail app can be deleted easily (unless the device is managed). Clearly the stock app "isn't" serving the purpose well.

Comment: i was under the impression that OS applications that come pre installed with the phone cannot be uninstalled. Did something change after the second generation in this regard?

Comment: Built-in apps can be uninstalled and reinstalled just like 3rd party apps starting with iOS 10. Please see the answer for more details.

Comment: Are you able to have these emails sent in non-HTML (text-only) format? Seeing that the HTML email format originated with Microsoft, and that the Microsoft Outlook app appears to work correctly, perhaps there is some HTML code in the email that is not parsable by iOS Mail. If text-only can be configured in SRSS, perhaps that is a solution.

Comment: i am skeptical about the possibility of html being the culprit since out of the 20+ reports sent only 2 of these have issues and even then the issue is that the atachment gets swapped with a copy of a different report, instead of being the proper one. Would seem to be an incredibly peculiar situation particularly since these reports use a template used in other, working reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Internet search has yielded that the problem is also being faced by others, but hasn't yielded any solution, it's most likely a bug with the stock Mail app.

A likely resolution would be to use the official email client app from the email service provider (Outlook in this case). Official app is more likely to work bug free compared to Apple's Mail app.

The stock Mail app can be easily uninstalled on devices running iOS 10 and later as outline in this Apple Support document:

- [Remove built-in Apple apps from the Home screen on your iOS 10 device or Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204221).